# ExtJS 4 URL is undefined when I try store.load()

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a Panel with multiple grids. I'm trying to make some kind of global refresh button by which I mean, a button that will refresh all the grids and open tabs, without losing data like when F5 is pressed.
  With two of the grids it was easy just get the store and load it but the third one makes a problem. When I try the same as with the previous two which works OK I get `URL is undefined`.
  Here is my code:

```
reloadInstructionsStore: function() {
    var reloadInstructionSt = this.getStore('Instructions');
    var activeCat = this.getActiveCategory();
    reloadInstructionSt.clearFilter(true);
    reloadInstructionSt.filter({
        filterFn: function(item)    {
            return item.get('category_id') == activeCat;
        }
    }),
    reloadInstructionSt.load();
},
```

The only reason I can think of is that the store that I use here is defined different from the other 2. It's not with PROXY and CRUD, but looks like this:

```
Ext.define('MY.store.Instructions', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MY.model.InstructionRecord',

    autoLoad: true,


    data: g_settings.instructionsApi.initialData

});
```

Is the problem here and is there a way to make things work even like this?

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reload this store, the data is provided on initial page load.  The variable `g_settings.instructionsApi.initialData` tells me that the data is available as static on the page.  All you need to do in this case is reset the filter, and just remove the `reloadInstructionSt.load();` call.

If you actually do want the data to reload from the server, you will need to give your store a **url** that it can get the data from and the server will have to be able to serve this data up.